# How do I list elements in the table with React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-frontend, dom-manipulation

I am new to React. How can I list elements from two different arrays in two columns using "map" function?

```
state = {
  dates: ["2000", "2001", "2002"],
  cases: ["1", "2", "3"]
}

render() {
  return (
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Cases</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {this.state.dates.map(el => 
        <tr>
          <td>{el}</td>
        </tr>
      )} // I want to list elements from "cases" array like this but in the second column
    </tbody>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you please show an example how `dates` and `cases` arrays look like? Thanks!

Comment: While you can make this work, as shown in the answers, this really isn't a sensible way to format your data. Instead of two arrays of the same length, this should be an array of objects, each object having `date` and `case` keys.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I've updated my answer to include the recommended solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick and Easy Solution:** *Not recommended*

If you're going to always assume that `dates` and `cases` will always be the same length then you could do this:

```
{this.state.dates.map((el, index) => (
  <tr>
    <td>{this.state.dates[index]}</td>
    <td>{this.state.cases[index]}</td>
  </tr>
))}
```

This method makes use of the `index` parameter of the `map` function. Then you can access the array at the specific index mentioned.

---

**Recommended Solution:**

The usual practice is to keep your data grouped per record.

Using your example, use a structure like this:

```
state  = {
  records: [
    { date: '2000', caseId: '1' },
    { date: '2001', caseId: '2' },
    { date: '2002', caseId: '3' }
  ],
}
```

Then implement it like this:

```
{this.state.records.map(({ date, caseId }) => (
  <tr>
    <td>{date}</td>
    <td>{caseId}</td>
  </tr>
))}
```

*I'm using `caseId` instead of `case` because `case` is a reserved word in JavaScript for `switch` statements.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index` parameter from the map function and access the cases array

```js
<tbody>
  {this.state.dates.map((el, index) => (
    <tr>
      <td>{el}</td>
      <td>{this.state.cases[index]}</td>
    </tr>
  ))}{" "}
</tbody>;
```